# CustomUI ribbon.xml onLoad event is fired only once at startup

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I created a CustomUI ribbon for my Outlook addin and here is the `ribbon.xml`:

```
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon1_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
```

and this is my `ThisAddin` class:

```
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{
  return new Ribbon1();
}
```

and here is my handling method:

```
public void Ribbon1_Load(Office.IRibbonUI ribbonUI)
{
   this.ribbon = ribbonUI;  
}
```

The issue is that the `Ribbon1_Load` event is dispatched only once, when Outlook starts, and not when a new email item is created.

What event should I use instead?

Answer (score 1):

The ribbon will be loaded only once - Outlook caches the ribbon XML afterward even if more inspectors or explorers are opened.

If you need  to refresh the state of a particular ribbon control, you need to invalidate the ribbon, which will trigger callbacks on the control level.

Comment: How simply invalidate the ribbon ?

Comment: You can't - ribbon xml is assumed to be static. If you want to show/hide various controls depending on some conditions, do that  by invalidating the ribbon and handling the getVisible callback on the controls.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this, you need to use an `Inspector` as described in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019).